# Trying to make AJAX calls less clunky

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, design-patterns

I recently read a blog post about having your code rely as little on the DOM as possible (i.e. keep as much out of the $(document).ready() function as possible). I've been successful in doing this with things like creating view modules like this:

```
var View = function (e) {
  this.element = e;
};

View.prototype = {
  show: function () {
    this.element.fadeIn();
  },
  //More manipulation functions
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  var myView = new View($('#element'));
  myView.show();
});
```

I can't seem to find a way to wrap AJAX calls into an object so they're not depending on the DOM being loaded and so I don't have to write something like this every time I make an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "signout.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('An error occured while trying to log out.');
  },
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    settingsWidget.getAction('#settings').triggerAction(500, function () {
      WIDGETS.setOnTop('#login', SideEnum.RIGHT);
    });
  },
  complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {}
});
```

Is there a design pattern that I can use to achieve what I'm trying to do? Also, would it be best to pass the jQuery DOM object to the View object or just the selector and grab the DOM object inside of the View object?

Comment: well technically your whole module relies on DOM ready event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirtying up the DOM has always been a problem. Backbone.js is great, it helps give a lot of structure to your code. The module pattern by Douglas Crockford will help provide encapsulation for a lot of your code as well.

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

A great synopsis of some design patterns

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

And this is what I currently use as a design pattern

https://github.com/bmarti44/jq-mod-pat

What you use is up to you, but you should be fine doing ajax calls with any of these patterns. Hopefully one of these will give you some inspiration.

Comment: These are awesome resources and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into `$.ajaxSetup()`? I have all my common ajax options setup for me once and then every time you make a `$.ajax()`, `$.getJson()`, `$.post()`, ect.. it uses all your defaults you predefined in your setup. As for not depending on the dom, being unintrusive as much as possible is very good! Have a look at backbone.js, it may solve all your problems including the setup and View.prototype as it does all that for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I actually have looked into it, but that usually only helps with a few settings like type, dataType, and error. I've heard a lot about backbone.js but have yet to look into it, I'll get on that asap. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Worth a look: [**Global Ajax Event Handlers**](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you and idea of what you should do:

```
var View = function(e) {
  this.$el = e; //using "$" before variable with jquery object is better for reading code
  this.$settings = $('#settings');
  this.login = $('#login');
}


View.prototype = {
  show: function() {
    this.element.fadeIn();
  },

  signOut: function() {
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        url:                "signout.php",
        type:               "POST",
        dataType:           "json",
        error:          function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occured while trying to log out.');
        },
        success:            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          self.someAction();
        },
        complete:           function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        }
    });

  },

  someAction: function() {
    var self = this;
    settingsWidget.getAction(self.settings).triggerAction(500, function() {
      WIDGETS.setOnTop(self.login, SideEnum.RIGHT);
    });
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what you should pass within getAction and setOnTop functions as arguments but I give you an idea how to cache objects and make them some kind of class variables.